# Java Set Text Color in Disabled SWT Text Field

Tags: java, text, colors, swt

I am using a disabled SWT text field (`import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text`) and I basically want to set the text color.

I know in `JTextField` you can use `setDisabledTextColor(Color c)` to set the color of the disabled text but is there something for an swt widget text filed?

Any help / suggestions greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Color of disabled component is one of those things which is regulated by the OS, so it's not possible to change that color in SWT.

You could however add a `Listener` to `SWT.Paint` and draw something yourself.

---

You can use this as starting point:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();

    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));

    final Text normal = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    final Text special = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    special.addListener(SWT.KeyUp, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event e)
        {
            normal.setText(special.getText());
            special.redraw();
        }
    });

    special.addListener(SWT.Paint, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event e)
        {
            if (!special.isEnabled())
            {
                GC gc = e.gc;

                String text = special.getText();
                Rectangle bounds = special.getBounds();

                gc.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_TITLE_INACTIVE_BACKGROUND));
                gc.setForeground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_TITLE_FOREGROUND));
                gc.fillRectangle(0, 0, bounds.width, bounds.height);
                gc.drawText(text, 3, 2);
            }
        }
    });

    normal.setEnabled(false);

    Button switchButton = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
    switchButton.setText("(De)activate");
    switchButton.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event e)
        {
            special.setEnabled(!special.getEnabled());
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
}
```

Looks like this (first `Text` is the default, second `Text` is the custom one:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will get on this first thing in the morning. If you could provide pseudo / sample code that would be a great benefit & I will accept your answer!